# Call DataSource method in awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, objective-c, datasource, awakefromnib

So the question is like this:

I subclass 2 classes, which is UIView(name: Menu) and UIViewController(name: MainController). In Menu, i used xib file to create it layout. In MainController, i added Menu as subview like this and comform to protocol in Menu.

```
SliderMenu *sliderMenu = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SliderMenu" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
sliderMenu.datasource = self;
sliderMenu.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:sliderMenu];
```

The layout works perfectly, there is no problem with it.

The problem is with DataSource. i call a datasource method in **awakeFromNib**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Alloc data
self.data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.datasource arrayOfData]];
}
```

and that never even get called. After trying and trying i found out that, `sliderMenu.datasource = self;`is run after **awakeFromNib**. Thats is why the datasource method in MainController is never get called.

Question:
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Move your code from `awakeFromNib` to somewhere after `datasource` assignment

Comment: i have tried that, no work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint in `-awakeFromNib` method, you'll see that this method executes as it should.
The thing is, that this method called before datasource assignment, and at this moment your `self.datasource` is `nil`.
I suggest you to override the setter of the `datasource` property and initialize your data there, e.g.

```
- (void)setDatasource:(id<YourProtocol>)datasource
{
    _datasource = datasource;
    self.data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[datasource arrayOfData]];
}
```

OR

make a public method, say, `prepare` and do all your initialization there,

```
- (void)prepare
{
    self.data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.datasource arrayOfData]];
}
```

and call this method after datasource assignment:

```
SliderMenu *sliderMenu = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SliderMenu" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
sliderMenu.datasource = self;
sliderMenu.delegate = self;
[sliderMenu prepare];
[self.view addSubview:sliderMenu];
```